# Custom Button with conditional image and conditional text

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have the following custom QML `Button`:

```swift
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Rectangle {
    id: ueButton

    property string ueText: ""
    property string ueIconPath: ""

    width: 256
    height: 128

    signal ueSignalButtonClicked

    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop {
            position: 0

            color: "#ffffff"

            SequentialAnimation on color {
                id: ueButtonClickAnimation

                loops: 1
                running: false

                ColorAnimation {
                    from: "#ffffff"
                    to: "#000000"
                    duration: 25
                }   // ColourAnimation

                ColorAnimation {
                    from: "#000000"
                    to: "#ffffff"
                    duration: 25
                }   // ColorAnimation
            }   // SequentialAnimation
        }   // GradientStop

        GradientStop {
            position: 0.418

            color: "#000000"
        }   // GradientStop
    }   // Gradient

    border.color: "steelblue"
    border.width: 1
    radius: 4

    antialiasing: true
    smooth: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true

        Image {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop
            Layout.margins: 8

            asynchronous: true

            horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter

            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

            smooth: true

            source: ueIconPath
        }   // Image

        Text {
            text: ueText

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter
            Layout.topMargin: 8
            Layout.leftMargin: 8
            Layout.rightMargin: 8
            Layout.bottomMargin: 16

            color: "#ffffff"
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pointSize: 16
            textFormat: Text.RichText
        }   // Text
    }   // ColumnLayout

    MouseArea {
        id: ueButtonMouseArea
        antialiasing: true

        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            ueButtonClickAnimation.running=true
            ueSignalButtonClicked()
        }
    }   // MouseArea
}   // ueButton
```

This works fine, but what I want to do now is to solve the following two issues:

1. If `urtext` is empty, the corresponding text is ignored and the whole `ColumnLayout` place is reserved for `Image`.
2. If `ueIconPath` is empty, the corresponding image is ignored and the whole `ColumnLayout` is reserved for `Text`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BaCaRoZzo already suggested, using styles is preferable solution in this case since the item itself is still `Button` and so you can use all its properties and signals, including `text` property to pass your `ueText` text.

As for hiding elements inside, you can use `visible` property as suggested below:

**UeButton.qml**

```js
Button {
    id: ueButton
    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: control.pressed ? "#CCC" : "#DEDEDE"
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "#999"
            radius: 3
        }
        label: ColumnLayout {
            id: layout
            spacing: 10
            Image {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                source: control.iconSource
                visible: control.iconSource !== ""
            }

            Text {
                text: control.text
                visible: control.text !== ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now using of this component is similar to regular `Button`:

```js
UeButton {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "Some text"
    iconSource: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"
}
```

Commenting out `text` or `iconSource` will change the button view